# Execute Apex code as part of Report in Lightning

Tags: lightning-experience, reporting

Is it possible to execute a block of Apex as part of running a report in Lightning Experience?

Specifically, i want the report to parse some JSON that is stored in a text field in a custom object.

Answer (score 0):

It is not.

You can run Apex upon *viewing* a record only if you surface custom UI components, such as Visualforce pages or Lightning components, on the relevant user experience element, such as a Page Layout, Lightning record page, or Lightning utility bar.

Accessing records more generally, including via SOQL and reporting, doesn't offer any hooks for running code elements and doesn't modify records other than updating viewership information.

You can, however, programmatically execute a report or dashboard in Apex, digest its results in any way appropriate to your application, and then display the resulting data through your preferred custom UI enriched or formatted however you require, by harnessing the [Reports and Dashboards API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_analytics_intro.htm#!).

Comment: i don't really need to modify records. I want to do things like a report where the product name is in the `["a", "b"]` where that second value is stored in a custom field of a custom object. And the total number of records may be in the hundreds of thousands.

Comment: @zaitsman It's not possible to do that in standard Salesforce reporting. You'd need to build a custom report in Visualforce or Lightning. (Additionally, standard tabular reports have a 2,000 row limit when viewed in the UI).

Comment: Cool. How do i `build a custom report`. Or did you mean 'create Apex controller to select data and then some UI to render it'? How would i then e-mail it to people?

Comment: I meant the latter, I am afraid. But if you're dealing with hundreds of thousands of records, there's a lot of platform limits you may run up against, including particularly SOQL rows and heap size.

Comment: At that scale, careful architectural review will be needed, and you may need to use an asynchronous process to digest the data into some intermediate object that can be reported on, emailed, etc. If you actually need to extract and transmit hundreds of thousands of records, an external BI tool or the Bulk API is more appropriate.